# php call from variable method of variable object: how to indicate this

Tags: php, variables, object, methods

First of all sorry for my english.
I try to explain with an exaple.

```
class Test{
    protected $functions = ['a'=>'function1', 'b'=>['ClassX', 'methodY']];

    public function exaple($value, $type){
        $k = call_user_func($this->functions[$type], $value);
    }
}
```

In this way the method can apply diffent functions to the value depending from type.
If i need to call a function put in the "functions" array only a string, otherwise i put an array with class name and method name.
In this way all works fine.

The problem comes when i need to put in the "functions" array a method of the "Test" class.
Bypassing the array i can write:

```
call_user_func([$this, 'localMethod'], $value);
```

and this work.
But when i try to put it in the "functions" array i don't know how to specify `$this`
Here the new exaple:

```
class Test{
    protected $functions = ['a'=>'function1', 'b'=>['ClassX', 'methodY'], 'c'=>['$this','localMethod']];

    public function exaple($value, $type){
        $k = call_user_func($this->functions[$type], $value);
    }

    public function localMethod($value){
        [...]
    }
}
```

In this way it doesn't work.
I've tryed in different ways:

```
'c'=>['$this','localMethod']
'c'=>['this','localMethod']
'c'=>[$this,'localMethod']
```

but with no luck.

Anyone can help me? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference `$this` before the class is instantiated. You have to add those methods in the class's constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->functions['c'] = [$this, 'localMethod'];
}
```